# Conditions such that $x^{\top}Ax>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

I know that a sufficient condition such that the quadratic form $x^{\top}Ax>0$ is positive is that eigenvalues of $A$ are all positive, but is there any weaker condition , e.g a condition depending on the vector $x$?

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, then "$x^\top A x > 0$ for nonzero $x$" is equivalent to "eigenvalues of $A$ are positive."

Comment: What if $x=0$??

Answer (score 2):

If the inequality $x^{\top}Ax > 0$ holds for every vector nonzero vector $x$, we say that $A$ is a *positive definite* matrix. There are a list of criteria that you can read [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html). An interesting necessary criterion (that isn't listed in the previous link) is that positive definite matrices must have all their diagonal entries positive.

Comment: Thank you. I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question about conditions depending on the vector $x$. You can relax the condition of the matrix being positive semidefinite by constraining your vector $x$. For example, a matrix for which $x^T A x \geq 0$ where every entry in $x$ is positive is called copositive. I'm also struggling with a problem like that. You can view the ongoing discussion in this forum.